# Visiting Schengen countries with travel document and green card (obtained through the refugee status)

Tags: visas, legal, paperwork, refugees, stateless-persons

I'm a permanent resident of the USA with a green card obtained as a direct result of refugee status (refugee from Russia). I have a travel document issued by the USA (I-571). I am planning to travel to Europe for a month to visit my relatives there (they'll be flying from Russia) and visit around 8 European countries. The closest is approximately 600 miles away from Russia. I am going to get a Schengen visa for my Travel Document and not going to use my Russian passport. Should I have listed all the countries I am planning to visit in my application for the Travel Document (I-131)? What are the chances that I won't be allowed back to the US? Will it have a negative impact on my future citizenship application? Has anyone done it before?

Comment: If you already have a refugee travel document, why are you applying for another one? Is it expiring?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Oh sorry, the original question was "Should've I listed",but it was edited by somebody.

Comment: What countries did you specify on the application, and why didn’t you list all those you were intending to visit? Just from looking at the guidance notes to the I-131, I see it states *Any travel document obtained by making a material false representation or concealment in this application will be invalid* and *If you knowingly and wilfully falsify or conceal a material fact or submit a false document with this request, we will deny your Form I-131 and may deny any other immigration benefit. In addition, you will face severe penalties provided by law and may be subject to criminal prosecution*

Comment: Perhaps the safest thing to do (if you have time) is to reapply for a new I-571, with the full details of your trip?  You will of course need to return your existing I-571 as part of the application process.

Comment: Or change the planned trip to conform to the application, and only visit the countries you listed.

Comment: The reason why not all the countries listed is because I filled out my I-131 10 months ago and was planning to visit fewer countries, but now, after your suggestions, I will definitely reapply for a new travel passport. But other than that, I should be okay, right?

Comment: If the information was correct at the time you made your application, then you did not make a false representation or concealment (though that may be hard to prove if ever challenged; that said, I doubt they’d find out or much care—but is it worth the risk if you can do things completely legit?).  There may be an interim solution, of asking the govt for guidance on what you should do in this predicament.

Comment: Please edit the question to restrict it to a single query. Add more questions if you need to ask more. Thank you.